# Angular 8 : Error in Document is not defined : Entrypoint = index.html

Tags: angular

ERROR in document is not defined
Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "index.html" = index.html

This is for Windows OS. I am using "html-webpack-plugin": "3.0.7"

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = function() {
  return {
    entry: "./src/main.ts",    
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/dist",
      filename: "app.js"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "@ngtools/webpack" },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" }        
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + "/src/index.html",
        output: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "index.html",
        inject: "head",
        title: "My Demo Application"        
      }),
      new ScriptExtPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: "defer"
      }),
      new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json",
        entryModule: "./src/app/app.module#AppModule",
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ]
  };
};
```

Not building successfully using Webpack